# Access Custom Class in ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf

I am trying to implement a SharedResourceDictionary in my WPF Application.

Christian Moser has written a short article and supplied the class here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html

I copied his class into a file of my own called SharedResourceDictionary.cs
My problem arises when I try to  implement the XAML below in one of my resource dictionaries. Is there something I should be doing in my ResourceDictionary to gain access to the class?

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   <SharedResourceDictionary Source="/Brushes.xaml"  />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was shown the answer by a colleage, and I did not need a namespace.

I needed to place the SharedResourceDictionary.xaml into a seperate assembly. There is a long technical reason why this is the case, but I do not have my head around it enough to give a detailed explanation here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the namespace.

Suppose the SharedResourceDictionary class resides in the MyTools namespace and is implemented in the MyCoolTools.dll assembly:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:tools="clr-namespace:MyTools;assembly=MyCoolTools">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <tools:SharedResourceDictionary Source="/Brushes.xaml"  />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```